# Error in jags.model

Tags: r, jags, runjags, rjags

I'm new to R and JAGS, and not even very experienced with programming.

I'm trying to set up a hierarchical model for some data, but I get this error:

```
####error in line above:
Error in jags.model(file = "modelControl.txt", data = dataList, inits = 
initsList,  : 
  RUNTIME ERROR:
Cannot insert node into beta1[1:158]. Dimension mismatch
```

At the end of running the code below.  What am I doing wrong?  How can I avoid the error?

```
#declaration
y=as.numeric(PANSS[treat == 0]) #treat == 0 indicates control group
x=as.numeric(time[treat == 0])
meanYcontrol = mean(PANSS[treat == 0])
sdYcontrol = sd(PANSS[treat == 0])
s = pp[treat==0]

#data list
dataList = list(
  y = y,
  x = x,
  Ntotal = length(y),
  Nsubj = length(y)/6 , #each subject had 6 test moments
  s = s
)
#model
modelString = "
model {
for ( i in 1:Ntotal ) {
y[i] ~ dnorm( beta0[s[i]] + beta1[s[i]] * x[i,1], 1/sigma^2 ) 
}
for ( j in 1:Nsubj ) {
beta0[j] ~ dnorm( beta0mu , 1/(beta0sigma)^2 ) 
beta1[j] ~ dnorm( beta1mu , 1/(beta1sigma)^2 )
}
#vague priors
beta0 ~ dnorm( 0, 1/(10)^5 )  
beta1 ~ dt( 0, 1, 1 ) #Cauchy distribution
beta0sigma ~ dunif( 1.0E-5, 1.0E+5 )
beta1sigma ~ dunif( 1.0E-5, 1.0E+5 )
sigma ~ dunif( 1.0E-5, 1.0E+5 )
nu = nuMinusOne+1
nuMinusOne ~ dexp(1/29)
}
"

 #write model to text file
writeLines(modelString, con="modelControl.txt")

#initialization chains
beta0Init = meanYcontrol
beta1Init = 0
sigmaInit = sdYcontrol
initsList = list(beta0=beta0Init, beta1=beta1Init, sigma=sigmaInit)

#run chains
parameters = c("beta0", "beta1", "sigma") #parameters to be monitored
numSavedSteps = 7500 #number of steps in chain to save
adaptSteps = 1000  #number of steps to tune the samplers
burnInSteps = 500 #number of steps to burn-in the samplers
thinSteps = 1 #number of steps to keep (1=keep every step)
nChains = 3 #number of chains to run
nIter = ceiling(numSavedSteps / nChains) #number of steps per chain

jagsModel = jags.model(file="modelControl.txt", data=dataList, inits = 
initsList, n.chains=nChains, n.adapt=adaptSteps)
```

Comment: Under `#vague priors`, did you mean to define the priors for `beta1mu` and `beta0mu`? Because currently you have multiple conflicting prior definitions for `beta0` and `beta1`.

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable about jags... would it be helpful to provide some of your input data, like `PANSS`?

Comment: I see what you meant with regards to the priors. I changed beta1 and beta0 to beta1mu and beta0mu, I still get the same error though :(
I think the problem lays in my definition of Nsubj, would that be possible? here's a link to a screenshot of the data for the first 3 participants ibb.co/n6KL0v (I defined the variables before running the code above, naming should be correct)

PS: The code I'm using is similar to the code of an example in a textbook (doing bayesian data analysis, second edition p494).

Comment: y[i] ~ dnorm( beta0[s[i]] + beta1[s[i]] * x[i,1], 1/sigma^2 ) 
I changed the x[i,1] to x[i] as in my textbook example. Then I got a new error related to Nsubj. I changed to Nsubj = length (y)/6 to length (s). Now I got a new error’Error in setParameters(init.values[[i]], i) : RUNTIME ERROR: Dimension mismatch in values supplied for beta0‘ After removing init.values from my jags.model code it started working. I feel like I’m really close to the solution, I only need to figure out what’s wrong with init.values… does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your comments imply that you have changed a few things in your model, but the model definition in your question has not changed (or perhaps has been partially edited).  Here's what I think you are now using:

```
model {
for ( i in 1:Ntotal ) {
y[i] ~ dnorm( beta0[s[i]] + beta1[s[i]] * x[i,1], 1/sigma^2 ) 
}
for ( j in 1:Nsubj ) {
beta0[j] ~ dnorm( beta0mu , 1/(beta0sigma)^2 ) 
beta1[j] ~ dnorm( beta1mu , 1/(beta1sigma)^2 )
}
#vague priors
beta0mu ~ dnorm( 0, 1/(10)^5 )  
beta1mu ~ dt( 0, 1, 1 ) #Cauchy distribution
beta0sigma ~ dunif( 1.0E-5, 1.0E+5 )
beta1sigma ~ dunif( 1.0E-5, 1.0E+5 )
sigma ~ dunif( 1.0E-5, 1.0E+5 )
nu = nuMinusOne+1
nuMinusOne ~ dexp(1/29)
}

# In R:
meanYcontrol = mean(PANSS[treat == 0])
sdYcontrol = sd(PANSS[treat == 0])
beta0Init = meanYcontrol
beta1Init = 0
sigmaInit = sdYcontrol
initsList = list(beta0=beta0Init, beta1=beta1Init, sigma=sigmaInit)
```

So you give initial values for beta0 and beta1 but I think they are intended to be for beta0mu and beta1mu.  There may be further errors though - it is hard to check because at the moment we can't run the model as we don't have your data.  In the future, it would be a good idea to provide a minimal reproducible example, including any data etc that is required, as it will help to generate faster and more complete answers for you.

One way to avoid errors like this is to use the #inits# and #data# tags with the runjags package, which can help to make the data and initial values being used a bit more obvious e.g.:

```
model {
    for ( i in 1:Ntotal ) {   #data# Ntotal
        y[i] ~ dnorm( beta0[s[i]] + beta1[s[i]] * x[i,1], 1/sigma^2 ) 
            #data# y, x, s
    }
    for ( j in 1:Nsubj ) {  #data# Nsubj
        beta0[j] ~ dnorm( beta0mu , 1/(beta0sigma)^2 ) 
        beta1[j] ~ dnorm( beta1mu , 1/(beta1sigma)^2 )
            #inits# beta0mu, beta1mu
    }
    #vague priors
    beta0mu ~ dnorm( 0, 1/(10)^5 )  
    beta1mu ~ dt( 0, 1, 1 ) #Cauchy distribution
    beta0sigma ~ dunif( 1.0E-5, 1.0E+5 )
    beta1sigma ~ dunif( 1.0E-5, 1.0E+5 )
    sigma ~ dunif( 1.0E-5, 1.0E+5 )
        #inits# sigma
    nu = nuMinusOne+1
    nuMinusOne ~ dexp(1/29)
}
```

[Notice I have also used indenting to make the model easier to read - this often helps to identify mistakes without even needing to post the model]

Then in R you just need the data and inits specified to be in your working environment, and then use:

```
results <- runjags::run.jags("modelControl.txt", monitor=...)
```

Hope that helps.